# Spring POST method not supported

Tags: spring, controller, request

My spring application has GET Method working. Any try of creating POST method ends with the error below:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'POST' not supported.

Now I'm trying to create **request** as simple as it can.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/post/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> newReport(@RequestBody String aa) {
    System.out.println(aa);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("User created", HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**my controller**

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api"})
public class ReportsController
```

I've checked many threads of this problem, but none solves it.

Comment: Did you try setting proper content type in the request?

Answer (score 1):

You must delete '/' from the end of the service name:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> newReport(@RequestBody String aa) {
    System.out.println(aa);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("User created", HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything

Comment: The error is the same? Can you put the http request done? can you put the mvc spring configuration of the application?